# iOS constraint for one size class

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, view

I'm using size classes for my app, but I meet a problem.

Indeed, for my size class Regular x Regular (for iPad Mini for example), I set a specific contraint to one of my view. I set it size to 300 * 300 px. For other size class, this view has a size of 150*150px.

To do it, I "uncheck" the button "Installed" for R x R (for constraint width 150, and height 150), and after it, I set my constraints 300 * 300, checked for R x R.

The problem is, when I start the app, I can see my view has the size wanted BUT when I'm doing a log of this view, the size of this view is bad. My log shows me "150 * 150".... and it's a problem for me, because I used this size for other things.

It's hard to explain... If someone understands... I need explanations about this "bug" :)

Comment: I'm meeting the problem again :'(

Comment: Did you try updateViewConstraints ?